# groupby DataFrame by N columns or N rows

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'd like to find a general solution to groupby a DataFrame by a specified amount of rows or columns. Example DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(0, index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'], columns=['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4', 'c5', 'c6', 'c7'])

   c1  c2  c3  c4  c5  c6  c7
a   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
b   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
c   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
d   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
e   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
f   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

For example I'd like to group by 2 rows a time and apply a function like mean or similar. I'd also like to know how to group by N columns a time and apply a function.

Group by 2 rows a time expected output:

```
   c1  c2  c3  c4  c5  c6  c7
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Group by 2 columns a time expected output:

```
   0  1  2  3
a  0  0  0  0
b  0  0  0  0
c  0  0  0  0
d  0  0  0  0
e  0  0  0  0
f  0  0  0  0
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This groups by N rows

```
>>> N=2

>>> df.groupby(np.arange(len(df.index))//N, axis=0).mean()
   c1  c2  c3  c4  c5  c6  c7
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

This groups by N columns

```
>>> df.groupby(np.arange(len(df.columns))//N, axis=1).mean()
   0  1  2  3
a  0  0  0  0
b  0  0  0  0
c  0  0  0  0
d  0  0  0  0
e  0  0  0  0
f  0  0  0  0
```

Comment: After resetting columns, use `axis` in `df.groupby(by=lambda x: x/N, axis=1).mean()` for grouping by columns.

Comment: Luca, I said reset the columns `df.columns = range(0, len(df.columns))`? And, then apply `df.groupby(by=lambda x: x/N, axis=1).mean()`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36810595/calculate-average-of-every-x-rows-in-a-table-and-create-new-table `np.arange` would be valid for columns as well (you'd change it to `df.groupby(np.arange(len(df.columns))//N, axis=1)`