# How to calculate the quartile statistics of a column using the groupby function?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have data in 1 min intervals, and I want to change the granularity to 5 mins, and calculate the basic data statistics using .groupby as such:

```
   df2 = df1.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='5Min',closed='right',label='right')).agg({
                                        "value1":  "mean", "value2": "max",
                                        "value3": "quantile"})
```

I want to get quartile/quantile data as well, but can't assign specific quantile point. The default is 50th quantile.
How do I get the 75th quantile for value3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values you pass to `agg` don't have to be strings: they can be other functions.
You could define a custom function like

```
def q75(series):
    return series.quantile(0.75)
```

and then pass this to `agg` like

```
   df2 = df1.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='5Min',closed='right',label='right')).agg({
                                        "value1":  "mean", "value2": "max",
                                        "value3": q75})
```

You can even calculate multiple quantities for the same stat by passing them in a list:

```
df2 = df1.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='5Min', closed='right', label='right')).agg({
    "value1": "mean", "value2": "max", "value3": [q25, q50, q75]})
```

Comment: You might also find `groupby.describe` to be useful as well, giving a bunch of summary statistics (including all the quartiles by default) in one go. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.describe.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use `groupby.quantile` function. You will be able to specify the exact ***quantile*** and even choose a ***type of interpolation***. I'm not sure that it is possible to perform everything in one step. May be you may need to do it separately and then append a column with quartiles to a df.

Link to the docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.quantile.html

Comment: yeah, i was confused because my 5 data points for quantile calculation will be those 1 min interval values. 
data collected every minute ==> I want to group the data by every 5 mins==> add the quantiles to a different columns

Comment: there will be a quantile value for every 5 min interval, but im confused how to implement it.

Comment: May be you need to group by 5 rows, and then perform other operations. Possible answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46478518/groupby-dataframe-by-n-columns-or-n-rows